# dapr publish pub/sub failing on example

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, dapr

I have been trying unsuccessfully to publish a message through the pub/sub integration with Kubernetes

I am following the tutorial here:
[https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/howto-publish-subscribe/][1]

I have created the following component:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: snssqs-pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.snssqs
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: accessKey
    value: "..."
  - name: secretKey
    value: "..."
  - name: region
    value: "us-east-1"
```

Believe that the creds are tested from the same location, on the same AWS resources and they are working

The following subscription (even though as I understand the mechanics for publishing a message is not needed)

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: order-pub-sub-subscription
spec:
  topic: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:...:test
  route: /orders
  pubsubname: snssqs-pubsub
scopes:
- ubuntu
```

Note:

1.I also tried with just a simple queue name and not the arn

2.The ubuntu scope is just a simple ubuntu container that I query its DAPR localhost

Requests:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3500/v1.0/publish/snssqs-pubsub/test -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"orderId": "100"}'
```

and basically, any other path that I tried guessing all gave me the same error:

```
{"errorCode":"ERR_PUBSUB_PUBLISH_MESSAGE","message":"error when publish to topic test in pubsub snssqs-pubsub: error publishing to topic: test with topic ARN : InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: TopicArn Reason: An ARN must have at least 6 elements, not 1\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: 94ef825f-1d21-5b8d-ae4c-d8b43493104c"}
```

Nowhere in the documentation is anyone talking about any topic ARN, I tried to put it everywhere possible.... nothing seems to work on something that should be supported

Last thing:
I created a binding to SQS, that works with no issues.

[1]: dapr website

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If so, do you care (or remember) the solution or root cause?